# PHP / read txt files (or anything)

Tags: php, text-files, readdir

I've been searching for a while now, but php-noob as I am, can't get it to work.

What I'm trying to accomplish is a way to make directories in your root, with in each of them images + a txt file. So let's say you got:

```
 Root
 |
 +---Directory 1
 |   |
 |   +---Image1.jpg
 |   |
 |   +---Image2.jpg
 |   |
 |   +---Text.txt
 |
 +---Directory 2
     |
     +---Image1.jpg
     |
     +---Image2.jpg
     |
     +---Text.txt
```

I know how to read and display the images + names. But how do I display the accompanied textfile? (The content that is, not the title of the file).

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way is using file_get_contents ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php )

```
echo file_get_contents($path_to_file);
```

More advanced: fopen/fread http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Comment: for binary files and large files see Paulo's answer below.

Comment: file_get_contents() sucks the entire contents of the file into memory before returning, so for large files this will kill the script when PHP's `memory_limit` is exceeded. `readfile()` is a better option as it'll read/transmit the file in small chunks.

Comment: And how about a automatically display? Without defining the filename in PHP? Like.. Users can put stuff in a directory, and the code will read all of them and display it automatically.

Comment: first solution: use a database and store the path to the file which the user has uploaded. second solution: list all files in the user's upload directory ( http://php.net/manual/en/book.dir.php ) or use glob http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 0):

From PHP fpassthru manual:

```
<?php

// open the file in a binary mode
$name = './img/ok.png';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

// dump the picture and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Just omit the header calls and you can fpassthru your textfile anywhere in your PHP page.

Comment: Ouch, I've put this question in the comment above as well. How can I reply here? :P

Comment: Anyway, how do I make the script so.. That it will automatically read out the txt files from the dir's, without defining it's names in the php code.